# Explain GUI-less to beginners

Tags: terminal, user-interface

Yesterday I got asked:
"why a server does not have a display?" and
"why some applications have to run on the terminal, rather than having a nice look-and-feel UI/UX?"

While I had my technical answers, I felt like I missed something and was not really understood. From a beginner point of view all it matters is "where is the UI/UX?" "why I cannot use my mouse on that black-window (terminal)?"
Do you have a general, simple, plain-english, answer to such questions?

Thanks!

Comment: First, you’re asking about a GUI. A command line prompt is also a UI. I think the perspective is wrong. You say: “From a beginner point of view all it matters is ...”. Rather than explaining why a GUI isn’t required, one should try to explain why it *is* required. User experience, by the way, doesn’t need a GUI.

Comment: -1 If you  have to ask why you can't use your mouse on a terminal.. then forget it. Even the word terminal is a funny term. Try learning one command, are you going to ask why you can't use your mouse with the DIR command.. really. You're talking about a terminal when you don't seem to have ever used a command.. And you're using the word server when perhaps you don't even know what a server is. So you are asking the wrong questions.

Comment: I assume that sic2 knows what a server is, although the phrase "to beginners" in the title is misleading coming from someone who has got a PhD in computer science.

Comment: I know what a server is, and I know that a CLI is also a UI. I also know that you cannot use a mouse and all that on a terminal. The ones above are questions from real beginners or maybe people who have never done computer science, but still use servers and terminals (e.g. mathematicians, physicists, etc). Cheers. @karel if you can come up with a better title/question, please feel free to edit :)

Comment: Even physicists make mistakes sometimes, e.g. Stephen Hawking retracted his claim about black holes and the "Information Paradox". As for mathematicians, are we supposed to believe that anyone even knows anything definitive about some topics in machine learning and game theory? Personally I'd be happier if the word "UI/UX" was replaced by "GUI", but I don't have permission from those physicists and mathematicians to properly do it.

Comment: @karel - title updated. I did not mean to offend anyone studying/doing physics, maths. Mine was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "why some applications have to run on the terminal, rather than having a nice look-and-feel UI/UX?"
>
> "where is the UI/UX?" "why I cannot use my mouse on that black-window (terminal)?"

Because GUIs are really hard to program.

> why a server does not have a display?

Because some don't have graphics cards or their graphics memory isn't very big (it makes room for other hardware or for heat dissipation). Also, text is really easy to transfer and to make scripts with.

I would thinks something like a series of object lessons might help with this.

For instance, line up 4 people with pieces of paper and call them "window 1", "window 2", "window 3" and "desktop". Then have other students call out to them to come to the front of the line and do something, but make the person doing the calling attempt to instruct the "windows" (in minute detail) how to move relative to each other. Do a similar thing with a single person and call them "terminal". While more of a demonstration of a windowed vs. non-windowed environments, this might help with the point.

An abstraction of the graphics memory "issue" similarly might be simply giving the students a really small scrap of paper (representing the graphics memory of a server) and asking them to choose to write down a series of words (commands) or try to draw a full-fledged icon-based interface on the same piece of paper.

There may be other ways to demonstrate the complexity or bulk of file data vs. text based instructions or keeping track of mouse pointers relative to icons.

These examples may not be good ones for accuracy so you may wish to come up with more precise ones for the questions you're receiving but hopefully this approach might be a stepping stone for those who REALLY don't understand any basic computer concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, you don't need it. Software that's simple is easy to maintain and keep secure.

A Gui is extra 'bloat' in many cases, and gives a broader base of software to attack. In essence *good* software is minimal, and the 'unix' philosophy of simple single purpose software (one thing well) and reasonably human readable configuration is simpler to maintain (and automate!) once you have grasped the basics. I can replicate my configuration by hand with 2-3 commands (that is to say, I copy over my package list, install the software with it, and copy over a few directories). A gui on the other hand means clicking, dragging and *less precision*.

A command is more precise than a text user interface, which is lower in resources than a gui.

Answer (score 0):

From a technical perspective, the Terminal is itself a GUI through which you can use the [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) commands.

**In most cases, we use server for other reasons than graphical needs**. That's why.

However, if you want to have a graphical view of your server as when you are using your PC,  you may install the desktop modules (if you want to administer your server locally); you can read this post ([How do you run Ubuntu Server with a GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui)) in case you are running an Ubuntu server. If you want to administer your server remotely (which is almost always the case) you can also install client/server graphical modules depending on your Linux distribution ([X2GO](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php), for example)

Answer (score 0):

GUIs increase in frequency with user engagement. The more the work needs a human operator and the more that operator needs to have visual access to their work, the more a GUI is needed. Examples of this are web browsers and photo editors.

CLIs are more efficient when the computer is doing the majority of the work, at which point, understanding and navigating the GUI becomes unnecessary overhead for the operator, the programmer, and the computer.